# Remote website resource consumption

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I'm refactoring the code of an existing website "home made". When I open some pages my CPU consumption jumping by 20%...

I'm used to Firefox development tools, but everything seems to be calm after the page is loaded. I guess it's a javascript running in circle but I don't know how to catch it.

Do you know a way to spot the right script? Is there something exisiting similar to resource consumption but at the website scale?

Comment: If you were to use Chrome, there is a JavaScript CPU Profiler in the DevTools that will tell you what it is hanging up on. :)

Comment: Read about profiling. [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling) has a great instruments for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your website for performance test.
Some simple websites and browser plugins can show the exact javascript which is taking time (If only javascript is the real issue. If other things are also helping in cpu util then these plugins can point you to them.)

1. GTMetrix - website which can help you find bottlenecks in your website
2. pagespeed - chrome plugin which is really good plugin to find bottlenecks as well as improved javascripts. this plugin can pin point your culprit javascript and will provide you optimized/minified version of it. Of course if only java script is the actual bottleneck.
3. firebug - mozilla plugin in firefox which also can perform same job but wont give optimizations.

meanwhile you can monitor your system resource util. and make sure that nothing else is running on your client other than website to make sure that util is because of those 2-3 pages.

Based on suggestions provided by above tools/profilers, decide your optimization candidates.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, tools and ideas.